# Address of pass-by-value variable causing seg-fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pass-by-value, lapack, blas

I'm working with some legacy code that I cannot edit that was originally compiled for and tested on PowerPC.  I am attempting to create a build system that will build it for generic linux box (Ubuntu 11.10 x64).

It has a custom interface similar to cblas that wraps an f2c version of the generic blas library included in clapack (Ver. 3.2.1).  I.e. I compile liblapack, libblas and libf2c on the linux machine from the clapack source and link it with the following example code:

```
int main()
{
    double a[3] = {100,200,300};
    // Scale all elements of a by 0.1
    // This uses a custom wrapper that seg. faults
    mycblas_dscal(3,0.1,a,1);
}

void mycblas_dscal(int N, double scale, double* data, int inc)
{
    dscal_((int*) &N, (double*) &scale, data, (int*) &inc);
}
```

`mycblas_dscal` simply calls the blas library implementation `dscal_`.  However the library expects pointers for all data and this wrapper currently passes the address of `N`,`scale` and `inc` directly.  This scares me since they are passed by value and are often literals.

When executed `mycblas_dscal` often does nothing, i.e. `a` is unchanged or it seg. faults.  With higher compiler optimizations (e.g. gcc -O3) it only ever seg. faults.

To test the blas library, the following code works fine:

```
int main()
{
    // This calls the library directly and works fine but I cannot edit 
    //the rest of the code which is using the wrapped version above.
    int size = 3;
    double scale = 0.1;
    int inc = 1;
    dscal_(&size,&scale,a,&inc);
}
```

My only insight is something to do with the address and persistence of pass-by-value variables in the wrapper function since the seg. fault behavior gets worse with compiler optimizations.  I don't know enough to investigate further.  Any ideas?

Comment: If `N` is declared as an `int`, then how come you have to cast `&N` to `(int*)`? It should already be an `int *`. The only effect of the cast would be to conceal any mistakes you might make -- until runtime, when you'd get undefined behavior. (And, likewise for all the other casts.)

Answer (score 0):

What this function

```
void mycblas_dscal(int N, double scale, double* data, int inc)
{
    dscal_((int*) &N, (double*) &scale, data, (int*) &inc);
}
```

does is to declare local variables `N`, `scale` and `inc` and pass their addresses on to `dscal_`. Since the variables are local, they live on the stack and cease to exist once `mycblas_dscal` is finished. The internal `dscal_` manipulates these local variables through their address. That manipulation affects only the local variables, it has no effect on the original variables passed to `mycblas_dscal`. Once you turn on optimization, I guess the `mycblas_dscal` call is *inlined*, further worsening the problem and causing seg faults.

**If you can change** `mycblas_dscal`, change it as follows:

```
void mycblas_dscal(int &N, double &scale, double*& data, int &inc)
{
    dscal_((int*) &N, (double*) &scale, data, (int*) &inc);
}
```

i.e. use references rather than values.

**If you cannot change** its definition because it's part of that library you mentioned, then the only thing you can do is not use that library. I don't think there is any other solution in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array as double pointer to the function, and handle the array using array's address in function. This could solve you problem.

```
int main() 
{
    double a[3] = {100,200,300};
    // Scale all elements of a by 0.1
    // This uses a custom wrapper that seg. faults     
    mycblas_dscal(3,0.1,&a,1); 
}  

void mycblas_dscal(int N, double scale, double** data, int inc) 
{     
   dscal_((int*) &N, (double*) &scale, *data, (int*) &inc); 
}
```

Comment: I fail to see what this accomplishes. `dscal_` expects a `double *`, and you sending it the address of a `double **`, i.e. a `double ***`?

Comment: yes, dscal_ expects a double*, where as i m sending double** to mycblas_dscal. its not a triple pointer. look at it closely. since dscal_ require a single pointer , thats why i m getting the value at double pointer to refer to the orginial array.

Comment: What you are passing to `dscal_` is `& data`. That means: the address of `data`. The address of a `double **` is a `double ***`.